# How to define accessors for a children?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have 3 classes :

```
public interface IParent
{
    String World { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public String World;
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello " + this.World;
        }
    }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    public String World = "World";
}
```

How should I do so that the get accessor of `Parent` is being called with the `World` attribute of `Children` ?

Comment: `this.World` will call the property recursively!

Comment: What do you want to be returned if I do `new Parent().World`?

Comment: Number of solutions below. There problem is sufficiently ambiguous that there are many different ways to approach the problem. If any of the below don't meet your needs, add more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second property for the suffix and make it virtual to allow the descendants to overwrite it

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    protected virtual string Suffix => "World";

    public String World => "Hello " + Suffix;
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    protected override string Suffix => "Again";
}
```

Parents will display "Hello World", Children will display "Hello Again". This is only true for the run time type. The static (i.e. compile time) type does not matter.

```
Parent p = new Children();
Console.WriteLine(p.World); // Displays "Hello Again"!
```

Here, the static type of `p` is `Parent`. The run time type is `Children`. This behavior is called [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

There is no way for a real `Parent` to know about the Suffix "Again".

Comment: No need to override here; if your intent is to allow the value to change just use a property with a (protected?) setter.

Comment: It is not clear what the code is supposed to do, since the OP's example neither compiles nor would it run without exception. But if you want to keep the "Hello " part constant and only redefine the following part in `Children`, then you must override.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams: While you could do this with a protected setter you would then actually need to add code in the constructor to set it and that would also allow other things to change it which may not be desired. This seems closer to the OP's seeming intent than your version.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes in this case you do not need to override because this solution adds a second property. The first property can be left readonly while the second can support a protected setter (or alternatively pass a value in via the constructor).

Comment: @Chris the intent hasn't been clarified by the OP sufficiently IMO. If the intent is that these things never be allowed to change (save through derivation), then an overriden read-only property is appropriate. If the intent is simply that the derived class be able to communicate these property values back to the base class, a simple setter is sufficient.

Comment: If the intent was just to display different values passed through the constructor, then you could do this with the `Parent` class alone. No need for a `Children` class.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Indeed. Or you could have a protected constructor that only derived classes can invoke if the intention is to only allow derived classes to change it. A number of ways to address the problem as loosely described in the OP.

Comment: Yes. Poorly formulated questions lead to long comment lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional private field which will be virtual, so you can override it in the child.

Try this:

```
public interface IParent
{
    string HelloWorld { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    protected virtual string World { get; }

    public string HelloWorld
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello " + World;
        }
    }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    protected override string World { get; } = "World";
}
```

Or you can also pass a string through the constructor, then you can set value at runtime.

```
public interface IParent
{
    string HelloWorld { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    private readonly string world;

    public Parent(string world)
    {
        this.world = world;
    }

    public string HelloWorld
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello " + world;
        }
    }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    public Children(string world) : base(world)
    {
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var children = new Children("World");
Console.WriteLine(children.HelloWorld);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is back to front.

It's down to the inheriting class to include base class behaviour from overrides ***if required***. The subclass `override`s the base behaviour, but has a hook to the base class via the `base` keyword.

As such:

```
public interface IParent
{
    String World { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public virtual String World
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    public override String World
    {
        get
        {
            return base.World + " World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to edit some stuff you intended to? Your `Parent.World` seems to be recursive at the moment.

Comment: @Chris Yes indeed. A typo has cost me a downvote. Fixed now. :( Thx

Comment: Wasn't me so I can't turn that downvote upside down. You can now have my upvote though if that's any consolation. :)

Comment: Yes, hate how fast people down vote typos - i got hit as well :/

Answer (score 0):

The property is already part of the parent. You'll want a protected set function however... Set it in the constructor like so:

```
public interface IParent
{
    String World { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public String World { get; protected set; }
    public Parent() { World = "Hello World"; }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    public Children() { World = "World"; }
}
```

However, perhaps you are looking for something more like this:

```
public interface IParent
{
    String World { get; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public String World { get; private set; }
    public Parent(String thing) { World = "Hello " + thing; }
}

public class Children : Parent
{
    public Children() : base("World") { }
}
```

Comment: Both of these result in compile-time errors, "`Parent` does not implement the interface `IParent`"... same for `Children`. You also can't set accessibility modifiers in an interface.

Comment: @RonBeyer - yes there were a couple typos. Fixed.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants though, you set it once when the object is created, but the OP is using properties and wants whatever the child is currently set to. In your case there is no child property that can be used by the parent to get a value to concatenate to the parent property. Really it is an X-Y problem on the OP's part, but I don't think this solves what the OP is looking for.

Comment: As far as ways to addressed the problem modeled in the OP as written the above are correct. It could be that what the OP is really after is the Suffix approach posted above by others, in which case that approach should be marked as an answer. However, unless the OP provides more details, these are correct solutions to the problem as described.